# How to use ajax on a field widget submit button in Drupal 7 without validating the rest of the form

Tags: ajax, validation, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm making a new widget for taxonomy term references where a submit button makes an ajax call back to drupal to alter the form.  Here's what I have:

```
$element['my_module_wrapper']['add'] = array(  
  '#type' => 'submit',  
  '#value' => t('Add'),  
  '#ajax' => array(  
    'callback' => 'my_module_ajax',  
    'wrapper' => $field_name . '_my_module_container',  
  ),
);
```

I have the ajax call working properly, but it validates the whole form, and throws errors when unrelated fields that are required aren't filled out.  How can I stop this?

Also possibly related, it doesn't seem to call my hook_field_widget_form() function when ajax is called... is this stemming from the same problem?

Comment: +1 I have the same problem with #states and am looking for the clean Drupal way to solve it (the hackish way being to overwrite the #validate array or educate users to fill all required fields before using UI elements that trigger #ajax or #states).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making your field #type = 'button' instead of 'submit'? As far as I know, a submit button will always run through the for validate array whether it's an ajax form item or not.

Comment: A regular button also triggers #validate callbacks :/

Answer (score -1):

Look at the example from Poll module given here: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax

The full function shows how it's done with '#limit_validation_errors'.